# Append id to request body key

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

```php
if (count($multiDestinationTask) > 0) {

            foreach ($multiDestinationTask as $task) {
                $task->destination_place = $request->destination_place_ . $task->id;
                $task->destination_address = $request->destination_address_ . $task->id;
                $task->destination_lat = $request->destination_lat_ . $task->id;
                $task->destination_lon = $request->destination_lon_ . $task->id;
                dd($task);
            }
        }
```

So, I want to get the request key by their id. I attempted to get the request key like the image before (appending the key name with the task id) but rather than returning the key value, it returns the task id.
[image]

The question is how can I get the value from the key base on their id from the controller?

The image below is the input form and how I concatenate the input name with id.

```
const placesMultiDestination = result.multi_destination.map((destination, i) => {
                return `
                <div class="row place-multi-destination">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Destination Place ${i + 1}</label>
                      <textarea rows="2" name="origin_place_${destination.id}" class="form-control" required autofocus>${destination.destination_place}</textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Origin Address ${i + 1}</label>
                      <textarea rows="2" name="origin_address_${destination.id}" class="form-control" required autofocus>${destination.destination_address}</textarea>
                    </div> 
                  </div>
                </div>

                `
              }).join('')
```

Comment: **Side note:** `if (count($multiDestinationTask) > 0) {` is redundant. Remove it.

Comment: @nice_dev its mandatory actually, if the data is null or empty, than don't execute the code. btw do you have the answer?

Comment: The `count` will error out for `null` anyway. For empty array, the foreach would work just fine without errors. See https://onecompiler.com/php/3yr94w2de

Comment: Can you also refine your question as it is too clumsy and confusing for now?